# Which array to insert to hash table for comparing two array

Tags: arrays, hash, compare

Last week I got an interview with Top software company.
And among many questions, I got this problem. To get common elements of two array using hash table which one will you insert into hash table.(Suppose there is no hash collision). Size of a array is much bigger than the other one. Can I get some explanation about it? I also want to know about the case with hash collision.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hash average case for insert and lookup is O(1) , so if we assume there is no collision and it's a perfect hash then the overall complexity for both cases will be (size of smaller and bigger arrays are 'm' and 'M' respectively)

```
M x O(1) + m x O(1)
```

If the hash has lots of collision and insert and lookup in worst cases are O(n) then it's better to have a smaller hash and put the complexity weight on the smaller one.

```
m x O(m) + M x O(m)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. So time complexity of hash depends on hash collision.

Comment: Yes. Things get messy in the real world. There's also the time required to re-allocate the table as it grows, and the resulting hash table occupies more memory. It is both faster and more memory efficient to make a smaller hash table in this case. Hash collisions are only one of the reasons.